# Adding a map in android without using xml?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

Can you add a v2 google map to an android app without adding it via an xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using the support map fragment as follows:

```
public class LocationFragment extends SupportMapFragment {  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);   
        return v;
    }


}
```

and you can add this Location fragment to your container as follows:

```
LocationFragment mapFragment = new LocationFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.your_container_id, mapFragment);
            ft.commit();
```

Comment: Sorry, I was expecting something like `MapView map = new MapView(this); lineaLayout.addView(map);`. Maybe you could explain your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Support Map Fragment is  a wrapper around a view of a map to automatically handle the necessary life cycle needs.It holds a mapview
within itself

Comment: Uhmm, could you tell me how to use this?

Comment: You can also use MapView directly, but you'll need to manage the lifecycle yourself. (Support)MapFragment handles this for you.

Comment: @chris please read the question heading.he wants map without using xml.

Comment: @Karan_Rana I'm not sure what you mean. I wasn't disagreeing with your answer. It was purely a recommendation to use a Fragment over MapView.